# How to disable Welcome to Xcode startup screen in Xcode 15?

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to disable **Welcome to Xcode** startup screen?
Before there was an option to disable startup screen "Help" -> "Welcome to Xcode" -> "Show this window when Xcode launches".
But in Xcode 15 there is no such option.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Apple removed the option to disable the "Welcome to Xcode" startup screen directly within Xcode 15. This has been a source of frustration for many developers.

However, there are still some workarounds you can try to disable the screen:

**1. Scripting:**

You can create a script that checks for the presence of the "Welcome to Xcode" window and closes it automatically. This script would need to be run automatically when Xcode launches.

Here's an example script using AppleScript:

```
AppleScript
tell application "System Events"
    activate
    repeat until exists window "Welcome to Xcode" of application process "Xcode"
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    close window "Welcome to Xcode" of application process "Xcode"
end tell
```

You can save this script as an application and place it in your Login Items folder. This will automatically run the script whenever you log in.

**2. Third-party tools:**

Some third-party tools, like "BetterSnapTool" or "Magnet," allow you to control window behavior and can be used to automatically close the "Welcome to Xcode" window.

**3. Command-line tools:**

You can use the osascript command-line tool with the AppleScript above to achieve the same result.

**4. Modify Xcode defaults (not recommended):**

While not recommended, you can directly modify Xcode's default settings to disable the welcome window. This involves editing a hidden file, and any future updates to Xcode might overwrite your changes.
Here's how to do it (at your own risk):

- Open Terminal app.
- Run the following command:

  defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode XCShowWelcomeWindow -bool false

This will write a value to the default settings file, disabling the welcome window.
Note: This method might not work in future versions of Xcode.

While these are some workarounds, it's important to note that Apple has not provided an official way to disable the "Welcome to Xcode" startup screen in Xcode 15. Hopefully, they will consider bringing back the option in future updates.